# Amazon CloudFront Signed URL "Access Denied"

Tags: iphone, ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an iOS app where I upload objects to an Amazon S3 bucket and want to retrieve from CloudFront distribution.

I am using CloudFront with private distributions for my Amazon S3 bucket and when I generate a signed URL it does not work, in Safari it returns AccessDenied AccessDenied and some random alphanumeric string, [My Signed URL I just generated (Expiration date in 24 hours)](http://d3c2hwoja895bf.cloudfront.net/shray-UploadedQuote-gcg157807710786912?Expires=1356320060&Signature=cP8Jhv4j2v1jhbwMC17KSmI3uYpRJPY-CajECQ36DKzi~xCPAAqxktFOm1FQVHoSogbM5cfZbOeupZH9OYXj8gdZzzXzut8tOoTmXKB~aN4qeNixJFN-EV~BaogWMPAexB31IlK~0r78zh6r~6yDHGI8cLxVAfWY0UtH5ZBWU7I_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJFXGRSBXF2C7HJNA) -- should be expired by now

I read the [following site](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/securityCredentials) to get all my security credentials in place and I have also setup a private distribution with my S3 Bucket by reading the [documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-task-list.html) and I have setup the [trusted signers](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-trusted-signers.html) which is basically just my account

I have used code from [this site](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=336955) to generate the signed URL

But again I have had absolutely no luck, when I put the link in Safari it returns AccessDeniedAccessDenied and some random alphanumeric string. Why? Any problem? Any step I am not following?

Thanks for any help! I appreciate it, this is important for me as I need to create an app where CloudFront would be very important for speed and international distribution...

---

Thanks everyone for upvoting, I figured out my problem. I didn't follow the step of create an access origin identity. Now it works like a charm. Woohoo!

Comment: Can you please list all the steps that you have done? It is difficult to go through the links and figure out what you have missed. This is a solved problem, so it is obvious you are missing something, so you need to list step by step what you have tried for someone to help you!

Comment: @d33pika Thanks, I will do this and update the question in a few hours.. got a lot to do first!

Comment: Have you tried posting in the aws forums? I usually get pretty useful answers from people there.

Comment: I actually solved my problem. I didn't follow the step of creating an access origin identity. I answered my own question with this detail, but a moderator deleted it due to lack of quality. After that I just got lazy to answer my own question so....

Comment: I see this question is relatively old... but I've recently experienced similar issue - the problem was related to the KeyPair used to sign the URL - you can find more details [in my original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54803307/how-to-generate-signed-urls-for-amazon-s3-exposed-by-cloudfront-using-net/54901185#54901185)