# How to generate signed URLs for Amazon S3 exposed by CloudFront using.NET

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, pre-signed-url

The thing I want to achieve is to generate a singedURL pointing CloudFront distribution which originates from S3 bucket.

I have managed to sign the URL which points directly to the S3 bucket as described in following AWS spec - [Generate a Presigned Object URL Using AWS SDK for .NET](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLDotNetSDK.html) and it worked fine.

But what I really need is to generate signed CloudFront URL.

I assume my Distribution is properly configured as I'm able to access it using (https://d298o8yem5c56d.cloudfront.net/123.pdf) assuming Restrict Viewer Access: is set to **No** in Behaviors settings.
After switching it to **Yes** it can no longer be accessed without signedURL.

I was trying to use the sample code from AWS Developer Guide: [Create a URL Signature Using C# and the .NET Framework](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreateSignatureInCSharp.html)

The [URL](https://d298o8yem5c56d.cloudfront.net/123.pdf?Expires=1550673983&Signature=q9HB7xBQRuZAVcuJsrO-H8NxCkbXv7YVEwydgc0fG1CSwNodKp3juHgd1Dw6wLAHzybGpO1dev-pRtHJUNugbcG9o9nLk3QiW5Hqy1Vty-JIidjateKxJeg9W6eyK5T3xbqDdXoov3MO3VVNFKGWVqD~uRbE8quIHzYtV3Du4Wc_&Key-Pair-Id=....) was generated, but what I get is following error message:

`<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access denied</Message>
</Error>`

Any ideas what should I check ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I've solved the issue using the sample code from AWS Developer Guide: [Create a URL Signature Using C# and the .NET Framework](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreateSignatureInCSharp.html)

The issue seem to be related to the PrivateKey.xml

Remember to replace PrivateKey.xml with your PrivateKey (which can be generated / downloaded from AWS root account settings). 
As a next step it has to be converted from PEM to XML (required by .NET)

Nice and easy way to convert from PEM to XML is by using an  - [online converter](https://superdry.apphb.com/tools/online-rsa-key-converter)

Comment: i am having some trouble as well to work with the AWS code example, i specific part i am missing, is what did you put in the "pathToPolicyStmnt", can you share an example of a policy that you used

Comment: If you value the security of your private key, I would be wary of using an online converter.